# CameraPreviewImageSource.StartPreviewAsync doesn't work with videoEncodingProperties

Tags: lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm using `CameraPreviewImageSource.PreviewFrameAvailable` event to determine flashes by calculating average luminosity of each frame.
For my purposes I don't need big frames, but with default settings `StartPreviewAsync()` method generates frames with size 1280*720px.
I tried to use `StartPreviewAsync(videoEncodingProperties)` but every time I get an exception `HRESULT:0x80040155 Interface not registered`.

I can set preview frame size through underlying `VideoDeviceController` object, but it looks overcomplicated a bit, especially concerning that I have to set properties in a magically determined sequence (otherway the camera will be broken after exiting from the app).

```
await App.CameraPreviewImageSource.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, _previewProperties);
var properties = await App.CameraPreviewImageSource.StartPreviewAsync();
properties.Width = _previewProperties.Width;
properties.Height = _previewProperties.Height;
```

Am I doing something wrong or `StartPreviewAsync(videoEncodingProperties)` method in SDK simply doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, "right" sequence of commands solves the problem:

```
var properties = await App.CameraPreviewImageSource.StartPreviewAsync();
await App.CameraPreviewImageSource.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, _previewProperties);
properties.Width = _previewProperties.Width;
properties.Height = _previewProperties.Height;
```